# Первый раз проиграли с одиннадцатой попытки

Tags: лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

***Первый раз проиграли с одиннадцатой попытки.***

Это тоже теперь нормально?

Comment: *Будем искать оговорки у спортивных комментаторов?* - не имею ничего против. Иногда очень полезно. Но это было сказано не спортивным комментатором, а диктором общеновостного вещания.

Comment: Не должно быть совпадением, однако кто знает: к вечеру 21.05.16 стали известны результаты игр футбольных кубков стран Европы, и впервые с 1902 г., выходя до этого 10 раз в финал, ФК Хайберниан, обыграв Глазго Рейнджерс (3:2), стал обладателем Кубка Шотландии.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка тут точно есть, но чтобы понять, в чём конкретно она заключается, нужен контекст. Если рассуждать без контекста, то явно лишний тут "первый раз", потому что предполагается, что если "проиграли с одиннадцатой попытки", то первые десять раз проиграть не удалось.

Но можно также предположить, что не предпринимались попытки проиграть, и подразумевалось, скорее, что они "первый раз проиграли на одиннадцатой попытке (сделать что-то)", и тогда "первый раз" лишним уже не будет.

Comment: Контекста почти нет. Показывают картинку с баскетбола - и диктор на голубом глазу уверяет, что *"Шанхайские барсы" первый раз проиграли в плей-офф с одиннадцатой попытки* (название придумал, конечно). А далее уже рассказывает, как это было, кому проинрали и почему.   *"Первый раз проиграли на одиннадцатой попытке (сделать что-то)"* - согласен, такое было бы вполне нормально, но смысл другой, вряд ли так кто-то станет изъяснятся. Нет, все что тут можно предположить, что первый раз проиграли в одиннадцатом матче плей-офф. И это, кстати, соответствует фактам.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь просматривается ирония. Если это устное "творчество", то в письменном виде его можно оформить так:

> Первый раз проиграли - с одиннадцатой "попытки".

Если исходить из этой записи, то можно предположить такой контекст: некая команда *впервые* проиграла. Известно, что *в данном виде соревнований* она участвовала до этого 10 раз и поражений не случалось, хотя всякий раз можно было этого ожидать. Ирония говорящего о "попытке проиграть" может трактоваться по-разному: это может быть его личный скептицизм (этой команде всегда везёт, а играет она всегда на грани поражения, будто в поддавки) или он имеет в виду ожидание поражения заезжей команды со стороны местной публики (для местных болельщиков это её условная попытка проиграть, наконец). Если смысл таков, то речевой ошибки нет.

Comment: Нет, сказано было на полном серьезе.